# Scalable architecture design for managing data flow in C++ using an Observer design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, c++

### What I need

I need a suitable and scalable solution to manage data flow between the classes in my C++ program.

### Why I need it

Upon new feature requests, I'm continually adding new classes to the program. I initially registered *callback functions* to classes and *injected a dependency* to the class via an interface:

[image: Callback Sequence]

Now, as the program *scales*, this is becoming quite difficult to *maintain* and *keep track of* where and when my data is flowing between class instances.

### My Proposed solution

I've now redesigned the system to use an Observer pattern. I have a central **event hub** (Observable) to which I can subscribe my various services (Observers) to:

[image: UML Design]

***Note:*** I've also implemented this as an example on [OneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3wuf5fm5d) and the code is also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cppengineer/51e8a440e9865837ce6e27e87f7f4b37).

I can also pass the event hub to the classes if they will also need to push notifications.

The new data flow will now be:

[image: New data flow Sequence]

### What I want to know

Before I embark on a refactoring mission I would like to know:

- Is the observer pattern as I've implemented it in the example, a scalable solution to manage the data flow between my classes?
- If not, what is a better alternative to ensure I can pass data between different sections of my program on an event-driven basis?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Seems almost like you're re-creating signals and slots.

Comment: That kind of depends on the problem you are solving. For example if this was an iterative simulation, an ECS would be better. If this was a a data transformation line, i'd look at pipe and filter architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I can address both comments simultaneously. This is for a simulation with a web user interface and a couple of socket connections with other systems. I'm trying to figure out how to share data and data changes between sub-levels of high-level class abstractions. Currently, I'm aiming for the signals and slots idea i.e. observer pattern and I pass interfaces down the hierarchy of both lanes for readback purposes. But, I'm going to have a look at both ECS and the Pipe and Filter thanks.

Comment: The `EventHub` that you've made is often called Mediator. I am not sure why/how the new solution must be better. If the problem was the apparent lack of a hierarchy in the data flow, then you should probably focus on just that, by enforcing layers and their separation.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain thanks for pointing out the Mediator. It looks like it will do the job and fit in better than the Observer for my use-case, thanks! I'm going to go with your advice for "enforcing layers and their separation" together with the Mediator design pattern to solve my problem.